# Using colour when inserting text in a buffer

Tags: colors

I would like print some text in either Green Blue Yellow Amber or Red?  How can I do it?

Have made the following function but calling

```
(mcolour "text" "red" "Mybuffer")
```

did not colour the text.

```
(defun mcolour (mesg colour buffer)
  "TODO."

  (let ( (buf (get-buffer-create buffer))
         (txt (propertize mesg
                          'face '(:foreground colour))) )
    (with-current-buffer buffer (insert mesg))
    (display-buffer bufferr)))
```

Comment: Paste the following snippet into an empty  `*scratch*` buffer and type `M-x eval-buffer`, or go to the end of the snippet and type `C-x C-e`:  `(let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*FOO*")) (txt (propertize "hello-world" 'face '(:foreground "red")))) (with-current-buffer buf (insert txt)) (display-buffer buf))`  See also the functions `put-text-property` and `add-text-properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code did not work because it is littered with typos.  Here is a working version:

```lisp
    (defun mcolour (mesg colour buffer)
      "TODO."
      (let ((buf (get-buffer-create buffer))
            (txt (propertize mesg
                              'face `(:foreground ,colour))))
        (with-current-buffer buffer (insert txt))
        (display-buffer buffer)))
```

In detail: you need `bufferr` to be `buffer` in the last line; `mesg` to be `txt` in the `insert` form and you must use the back-quote/comma mechanism to evaluate `colour`.

Comment: It was not having a comma.

Comment: The comma works together with the backquote: you were missing both. All the other typos could have been avoided with some care (or by cutting and pasting and formatting @lawlist's comment), but this one you introduced by making `colour` a variable that needs to be evaluated inside a quoted expression: since quoting inhibits evaluation, you need the backquote/comma mechanism to inhibit *some* of the evaluation, but allowing the evaluation of `colour`.